# Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details

Tags: apt

Just ran a sudo apt update and I got this message and I got this message which has to do with my anydesk application

http://deb.anydesk.com/dists/all/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

Can you tell me how to fix this and most importantly what this means? Trying to improve me Linux knowledge.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Fix Apt-Key Deprecation Error**

> sudo apt-key list

Depending on your system you may see a couple of entries appear or a veritable avalanche.

```
--------------------
pub   rsa2048 2016-06-22 [SC]
      D404 0146 BE39 7250 9FD5  7FC7 1F30 45A5 DF75 87C3
uid           [ unknown] Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
```

Copy the last 8 characters from the second line — in the example above this is DF75 87C3 — and convert it to a .gpg file using the command below. Remember to drop the space between the 8 characters and specify a gpg file name that is relevant to the package the key is for.

In my example I had to run:

> sudo apt-key export DF7587C3 | sudo gpg --dearmour -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/skype.gpg

Once you’ve constructed your command hit enter …That’s all you need to do.

When you next run an apt update the deprecated key error will no longer appear for the repo you just applied (though if you have more than one repo affected, you’ll need to repeat the steps above for each one).